# Finding minimum value of array from a certain point

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a recursive function that will return the smallest value of an array after a certain point which will be inputted into the function.

This needs to be done recursively without using loops.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int findMinpos(int arr[], int mid, int len){
  int minimum;
  if(len==1)
    return arr[0+mid];

  else {
    minimum = findMinpos(arr, mid, len-1);
    if(minimum<arr[len-1])
      return minimum;
    else
      return arr[len-1];
  }
}

int main(void) {
  int array[7]= {23,17,8,7,9,32,56};
  printf("%d", findMinpos(array, 2, 7));
  return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I could use some help.

Comment: This code outputs 7, which is the smallest value in the array.  Is that not what you expect?  If not, what do you expect and why?

Comment: recursion is the worst method for this task.

Comment: @P__J__ This particular task is better done with a simple loop in `O(n)`, but I suspect this is homework to teach [divide and conquer](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/merge-sort/a/divide-and-conquer-algorithms).

Answer (score 2):

`mid` is never updated.

Code "works" with the test case by luck.

---

> This needs to be done recursively without using loops.

Of course recursion is not required, nor advisable, to find the min `int`.

---

Although called `mid`, the `findMinpos(arr, mid, len-1)` implies code will call `findMinpos()` N times (N is the original array element count) **and** makes for a recursion depth O(N).

Such linear use of recursion, give recursions a bad name.

Instead, halve the problem each `findMinpos` call.

```
int findMinpos_alt(int arr[], int len){
  assert(len > 0);
  if(len == 1 ) {
    return arr[0];
  }
  int left_len = len/2
  int left_min =  findMinpos_alt(arr, left_len);
  int right_min =  findMinpos_alt(arr + left_len, len - left_len);
  return left_min < right_min ? left_min : right_min;
}
```

This calls the function N times, yet the recursion depth is O(log(N)).

---

More advanced code would use

```
int findMinpos_alt2(const int arr[], size_t len);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is homework to teach how to approach problems with [Divide and Conquer](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/merge-sort/a/divide-and-conquer-algorithms). This splits a problem up into two simpler subproblems which are then solved recursively. It's usually useful for sorting and searching.

Simply finding the smallest element in a list is overkill, it's O(nlogn) where a simple loop would be O(n), but it's teaching the technique. I hope.

In this case you find the smallest element of an array by splitting it in two halves, finding the smallest element of those halves, and then taking minimum of those. You keep splitting until you have just one element, that terminates the recursion.

[@chux already wrote the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375015/14660), there's no need for me to repeat that.

Why they want you to do it starting from a certain index doesn't make a lot of sense. I suspect what you're really supposed to do is use the midpoint to split the array in half and recurse like so...

```
int findMin(int arr[], int start, int len) {
  assert(len > 0);
  if(len == 1 ) {
    return arr[start];
  }
  int mid = len/2;
  int left_min = findMin(arr, start, mid);
  int right_min = findMin(arr, mid, len - mid);
  return left_min < right_min ? left_min : right_min;
}

int main(void) {
  int array[7]= {23,17,8,7,9,32,56};
  printf("%d\n", findMin(array, 0, 7));
}
```

This avoids having to do pointer arithmetic. Pointer arithmetic is generally faster and simpler, but often it doesn't get taught until later.

Comment: @chux I suspect the OP misunderstood what `mid` is for and the intent was to recurse as `size_t mid = size/2; int left_min = findMin(array, 0, mid); int right_min = findin(array, mid, size - mid)`